# Can this naïve-like set theory using acyclic membership be consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

The following theory contains a comprehension axiom that is a naïve-like schema. This theory definitely looks inconsistent at first glance. However, I tried to find this inconsistency, but to no avail. The main idea pivotes around an *acyclic* membership relation $\in^*$, so an acyclic member of a set is an element of a set that doesn't contain that set in its transitive closure. Now, this theory allows free construction of sets after all formulas in the language $\operatorname{FOL}(=, \in^*)$.

Formal workup:

Language: the first order language of set theory.

**Extensionality:** $\forall x \, (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) \to A=B$

**Transitive Closures:** $\forall x \exists t: t=\operatorname{TC}(x)$

$\DeclareMathOperator\TC{TC}\DeclareMathOperator\trs{trs}$***Define:*** $t=\TC(x) \iff \trs(t) \land x \subseteq t \land \forall k (\trs(k) \land x \subseteq k \to t \subseteq k)$

Where "$\trs$" stands for "is transitive", that is: closure under relation $\in$.

**Induction:** if $\phi$ is a formula, then:

$$\forall y \in x \ (\phi(y)) \land \forall k \,  (\phi(k) \to \forall l \in k  (\phi(l))) \to \\ \forall m \in \TC(x)( \phi(m))$$

***Define:*** $y \in^* x \iff y \in x \land \neg \, x \in \TC(y)$

**Comprehension:** $\exists x \forall y \, (y \in x \iff \phi^*)$

Where $\phi^*$ is a formula not using “$x$”, whose predicates are among $=$, $\in^*$ symbols.

**Questions:**

> Is there a clear inconsistency with this theory?

> If not, then can this theory prove Infinity?

Comment: What's $x(\phi)$ in the Induction schema?

Comment: @PeterGerdes it is $\forall y \in x \ (\phi)$, it means for all y in x such that formula $ \phi$ is true

Comment: Ahh, thanks...and yah I misread the comprehension axiom when I gave my first answer let me think for a moment.

Comment: In your various posts, you consistently write $``x''$, which looks awful (even in proper TeX, as opposed to MathJax)—for example, the two straight quotes in math mode appear as a double prime, not as a right double quotation mark.  Please use instead “$x$”.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice, agreed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I misread comprehension the first time.  Now that I understand it correctly can't you construct the standard Russell set:

$\phi(y) = \lnot y \in^{*} y$

So let's ask if the resulting $x$ satisfies $x \in^{*} x$.  If so then we have $x \not\in x$ which contradicts the assumption $x \in^{*} x$.

Now let's assume that $x \not\in^{*} x$.  But now that implies $x \in x$ so we must have $x \not\in TC(x)$.  But since $x \in x$ and the transitive closure is a superset of $x$ we must have $x \in TC(x)$.  Contradiction.

I haven't checked this carefully so maybe I made a dumb error but it seems right.

Comment: $\forall y \, (y \not \in^* y )$ is a theorem of this theory! So your set is the universe. Note that $`` x∈x→x∉TC(x)"$ is not a theorem of this theory, neither is $ z \not \in^* x \to z \not \in TC(x)$. You can indeed have $z \not \in^* x \land z \in TC(x)$ like for example the universe $V$, where we have $V \in V \land V \not \in^* V$

Comment: As I wrote in the above comment, your statement "so we must have $x \not \in TC(x)$" is unjustified. This is the error.